# Expected sizes returned by StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes

Tags: android, resolution, android-camera2

In the Android camera2 API, does the [StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes (Class klass)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap#getOutputSizes(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) method return always sizes that follow a format where **width is > than height**? Or do we need to test somehow if in some devices the height can be larger than the width?

I understand that some sizes may be in a 1:1 ratio, so width == height, but besides this specific case, do the returned sizes depend on the hardware? or will they always follow a **width > height** format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen devices where height > width, but there is no formal requirement that controls this. Worse, not all formal requirements are always fulfilled on all thousands of device models across the globe.

Actually, some devices do produce pictures (Jpeg) with height > width, if the app requests the picture rotated by 90°. Other devices may resolve such rotation by setting a flag in EXIF header only. Both behaviours are legitimate by Android standards.

Comment: As you state, yes, I’ve seen also how different devices produce different outputs, either rotating the Jpeg pixels or using the Exif header. Said that, in the use case I’m working on I'm querying a SurfaceTexture.class supported sizes by a using the StreamConfigurationMap, but with a requirement of only the 4:3 aspect ratio sizes. So, if there is no format requirement, although might be uncommon, should be the safest path to check first which is the largest most common side in the list (either width or height)? and then from the conclusion decide if testing for 4:3, or the reverse 3:4?

Comment: IMHO, there is no requirement that all sizes for SurfaceTexture have the same 4:3 or 3:4 aspect ratio. As I wrote, the question is entirely theoretical. Also, when we speak about rotated Jpeg, the list of supported sizes does not contain both landscape and portrait (*I wish it would*).